# What is the difference between executing script using Cygwin and PuTTY?

Tags: cygwin, putty, shell-script

Now I get a `script.sh`, previously it was executed using PuTTY provided it was written in VMWare, but now I want to execute in Windows using Cygwin, I already copy the `script.sh` out to the corresponding directory, but some commands Cygwin can not recognise.

```
generate(){
 date +%T
}

TIME = generate()
echo " Current Time: $TIME"
```

***After execute in Cygwin***

```
script.sh: line 3: syntax errot neat unexpected token '$'<\r''
script.sh: line 3:'generate<><
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your script. You can't have spaces around the equal sign in an assignment. In order to assign the output of a function or program to a variable, you have to use command substitution which means the command name is surrounded by `$()` (which is preferable) or backticks (which is less desirable). Also, when you call a function, you don't use parentheses after the function name like you would in other languages.

```
generate () {
    date +%T
}

TIME=$(generate)

echo " Current Time: $TIME"
```

The `$'\r'` error comes from having Windows line endings. You can use `dos2unix` to convert the file or use an editor that you can choose which type of endings to save a file with.

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

Comment: I still new in shell script, this troubles me when i follow a linux shell script book, it always execute in Linux environment but i try it in Windows, so there are problems appear. Thank you very much for your help